# How do I find patents owned by a a given university for a given topic programatically?

Tags: uspto, api

My end goal is as follows : 
Given a word and a university name, find all patents owned by the university in which the given word appears in the patent description.

e.g. word : machine learning 
university : Stanford University
Expected result : A list of all patents (or the total number of patents) by Stanford University in which machine learning appears in the patent description.

It would be great if you could please point me to resources that would help me achieve this.

Comment: I am not sure where to find full text search. Many commercial tools have it though, so it must be possible. Every patent office's website allows searching for owners (=assignees) (there is an answer somewhere around here listing a bunch of search tools)

Comment: Patents.google.com does this.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that this will show only those patents that were assigned to the University at the time of issue.
If the University as subsequently purchased more or sold certain patents, you will not be able to find from a public source.
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

The freepatentsonline.com expert search (www.freepatentsonline.com/search.html) is really robust free resource. Scroll down for the expert search.

To do the search you've described, check the box for US Patents (and uncheck any other boxes). Then enter: AN/stanford + "machine learning"  The AN stands for "assignee name" and entering "machine learning" searches every part of the patent. If you want to search just the specification, you could do: 
AN/stanford + SPEC/"machine learning"
Here's a URL for the Stanford search you described:
http://www.freepatentsonline.com/result.html?p=1&edit_alert=&srch=xprtsrch&query_txt=AN%2Fstanford+%2B+SPEC%2F%22machine+learning%22&uspat=on&date_range=all&stemming=on&sort=relevance&search=Search
I believe it's not possible to search *pending applications* for a company assignee, because law firms typically delay the assignee forms, and hence applications publish before an assignee is named in the application.

---

*I am no expert, and this response is for informational purposes only and not for the purpose of providing legal advice. You should contact your attorney or legal expert to obtain advice with respect to any particular issue or problem. Laws can differ dramatically from country to country, state to state, and technology field to technology field.*